# Google drive file access

Tags: php, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I am writing a PHP script which is supposed to pull some data from a google drive spreadsheet. Now, important thing here is that we're talking about one specific spreadsheet, which is on one exact google account. This data needs to be displayed on a site. That means that when a user visits this site, he/she should not need to login/authenticate or anything like this, because the spreadsheet being accessed is stored on one specific google drive account.

How do I pull this one? All I see online are examples where users login to their own account, viewing their own files which I don't need.
Thanks!

Comment: Get a refresh token for your own account, and exchange it for an access token when you need one via your php script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Drive access requires authentication. The only way I can think around it is to publish the spreadsheet using File/Publish to the web. You app can access the data using the published URL without authentication.